# Como modificar uma janela no Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

Como alterar a aparência do Window borde, Title bar e button, e status bar no Windows Forms?

Comment: Do Visual Studio ou dos programas que você cria **no** Visual Studio?

Comment: Programas criados no VS

Comment: WinForms ou WPF?

Comment: Window-form's !

Comment: O que você quer alterar, especificamente?

Comment: No momento foi mais uma duvida, mas acho que a cor ou o formato.

Comment: Jhonatas, é impossível alguém te responder uma pergunta se você não disser qual é a pergunta.

Comment: O formato então. Como mudo o formato meio arrendondado para retilíneo e uniforme?

Comment: Da borda do título?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nas propriedades do seu *form*, você pode escolher o *BorderStyle* entre algumas opções disponíveis fornecidas pelo próprio *VS*, e isto ira alterar os itens que citou. Todos estes estilos serão baseados no seu sistema operacional(Ex: se você tem *windows 8* suas bordas serão quadradinhas, se esta no *Windows XP* suas bordas vão ser arredondadas, ou qualquer *[Visual Style](https://www.howtogeek.com/168270/how-to-install-custom-themes-and-visual-styles-in-windows/)* que você tenha instalado)

[image: BorderStyles]

Você também terá outras opções como:
`ControlBox` (`true`/`false`): Exibe ou não os controles Minimizar,Maximizar, restaurar tamanho e fechar.
*Icon*: Define o ícone do seu *form* que sera (ou não, dependendo do seu *FormBorderStyle*) exibido na *TitleBar*, barra de ferramentas e no *Alt+tab*
e algumas outras(é só dar uma olhadinha nas propriedades que você vai encontrar todas!)

Se não gostar de nenhum, também pode setar o *FormBorderStyle* para *None* e criar seu próprio visual(*Aka* Gambiarra) e dar ao *form* o [formato dos seus sonhos](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=ironia)! [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]